# Writing and reading from binary

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct contact
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char phoneNumber[13];
    char email[50];
} Contact;

int dataBaseQuantity = 0;

FILE *f = fopen(".bin", "ab+");
if(f != NULL)
{
    dataBaseQuantity++;
    fwrite(&dataBaseQuantity, sizeof(int), 1 ,f);
    fwrite(&input.name, sizeof(char), strlen(input.name), f);
    fwrite(&input.surname, sizeof(char), strlen(input.surname), f); 
    fwrite(&input.phoneNumber, sizeof(char), strlen(input.phoneNumber), f);
    fwrite(&input.email, sizeof(char), strlen(input.email), f);
}
```

`cat .bin` returns `SQUAREIgnasKubilius+37065555555Ku@Ku.lt`.

Instead of a number I'm getting a square. Where is the problem?

Comment: And I cannot fread properly an int

Comment: A few problems here, but thats fine , you seem to be learning.  You can read or write the struct in one fread / fwrite command.  Do not use strlen as your data (name for example) is exactly 20 bytes long, you want to read/write 20 bytes not strlen

Comment: `sizeof( char )` is one by definition.

Comment: `&input.name` ->  `input.name`, etc...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216066/what-exactly-causes-binary-file-gibberish

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of every [IO function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) that you are using. Compile withj all warnings & debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger `gdb`**. Think to understand the behavior of your program. Improve it. Repeat till satisfied

Comment: The program asks to write your name, surname, phone number and email. the max lengths of these are in struct for example  name - 20 chars.

Comment: Write the whole struct in one go, but be aware that if you write a struct you will not necessarily be able to reliably read the data on another machine, or if you use a different compiler.

Comment: BTW, you might want to read about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). You could care about [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability), e.g. to system of different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Then you might consider textual -and more portable- data formats, such as [JSON](http://json.org/). Look also into [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), perhaps [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `fwrite`, which writes binary data. Thus, when you write an integer using `fwrite`, it does not format it as a string - instead, it writes the raw bytes that make up the integer. In this case, you're storing the number `1`, which, as a sequence of bytes (assuming 4-byte little-endian `int`s), is (in hex) `01 00 00 00`.

When you `cat` the file, it "automatically" removes the null bytes (more accurately, the terminal/console ignores them), but the `01` byte is printed as an unknown character, giving you the square you see.

There is no inherent "problem" with how you're writing the data, but you can't just use `cat` to display the data, since it works with text files, not binary.

Comment: And using some utility like [od(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or `hd` to dump that binary file could be helpful.